# Add androidx source code to Android Studio project for debugging

Tags: android-source, androidx

I want to to add the androidx source code to my Android Studio project instead of using the provided library (`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'`). Using the provided library I can only view the source code (it's read only during debugging), but I need to modify it for testing purposes.

So how can I add the androidx source code to Android Studio so I can edit it?

Comment: What is your OS? If it is windows you might have problems building it since they don't support windows.

Comment: I am working on a Mac so that won't be an issue

Comment: Have you checked the main repo page: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-core-release

Comment: in the section "Checking Out the Code"

Comment: this is the source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/core/core-ktx/

Comment: Thanks, yes, I checked that. This gives you the source code (only in the latest version though, for specific versions see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239207/androidx-googlesource-get-specific-version), but the question is, how would one add this or better the source jar to Android Studio?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Gradle fetches the `*-sources.jar` automatically; you're not going to edit that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler well, then I have another issue: sometimes in debugging the line numbers don't match. I hoped this could be fixed by manually adding the source

Comment: I found the recyclerView Source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget

Answer (score 2):

These repositories are usually being accessed with `repo` -
but for the sake of simplicity, `git` would also be supported:

```
git clone --branch androidx-master-dev https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support /home/android/androidx-master-dev
```

Android Studio also supports `git`; the repository URL to check out would be `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support` and the branch is to select is eg. `androidx-master-dev`;. However, manually adding the library modules you need might be better.

Only the pre-built artifacts have version numbers, not the source-code. And it might only be known internally, which commit equals which version number; it doesn't seem to be publicly documented. See [Android CI](https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-androidx-master-dev/grid?) and [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:); it says nothing about any version numbers there either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my question is not how to get the source, but given I have it, how do I add it to Android Studio so I can edit it? The source jars that Gradle automatically fetches are not editable in Android Studio / are readonly.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough points to add a comment...)

As Martin said, Google has created [a step by step guide](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support) how to download AndroidX, build it with gradle or Android Studio, make changes, import your custom build libs into your app, even contribute your changes upstream.