# Androidx Googlesource: get specific version?

Tags: android, androidx

I just downloaded the Androidx source code according to the description on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev

Now I want to have `androidx.core` version 1.1.0 source code.
I changed to `frameworks/support/core/core`but of course that's the latest version. So I had a look at `git tag`. It lists a dozen tags like

```
$ git tag
1.0_20180720
1.0_20180720_G
android-4.0.1_r1
android-4.0.1_r1.1
android-4.0.1_r1.2
[..]
platform-tools-29.0.5
support-library-27.0.1
support-library-27.0.2
support-library-27.1.0
support-library-27.1.1
```

but I can't see any tag related to `androidx.core`. So, how can I go to version 1.1.0 of `androidx.core`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong place. If you want to find `androidx.core`, you should find it here instead:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/androidx/internal/+/refs/heads/androidx-core-release

[image]

I already checked the commits and found core 1.1.0 from alpha to the stable version.

Comment: These are pre-built libraries, as the path may suggest. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60332864/549372) for the source code.

Comment: @MartinZeitler These are source code jars though :-)